# Negative lookahead - exclude entire match if words are found?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to parse text journals, and I am only interested in specific sections of text.
I thought that I was doing fine until I noticed I was inadvertently identifying sections.

Suppose that I want to match the following section.

> Section 7 - Delivering Terminal Diagnosis's

which may also show up as

> Section 7. Delivering a Terminal Diagnosis

But I don't want to match anything if the words see or under precede my string like below.

> see Section 7. Delivering a Terminal Diagnosis

or

> filed under Section 7. Delivering a Terminal Diagnosis

should not match anything.

I tried using a negative look-ahead, but it only excludes the words, it doesn't throw out the entire match.

```
((?!see )Section[\s\\n]+7[\s+]+?[-:\\n\.]+?[\s+]+?(Delivering|Deliver)(.*terminal[\s+]+Diagnosis('s)?)?[\.]?)
```

I don't think that I am grasping the look-around concept properly. help?

Comment: what's with the down vote? an explanation would be helpful otherwise I have no hope of resolving whatever deficiency there is in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following..

For whatever case you are using for matching, I would use `r` in front of your regular expression. `r` is Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns and to avoid escaping, and to avoid the fact of uppercase or lowercase to look for,  use `re.I` for case-insensitive matching.

Here's a possible solution using double Negative Lookbehind's.

```
(?<!see)(?<!under)\s+(section 7[\s.:-]+(?:deliver(?:ing)?).*?terminal\s+diagnosis(?:'s)?)
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/oA2sY4)

---

By example of using the raw string notation and `re.I`, this is what I meant.

```
matches = re.findall(r"(?<!see)(?<!under)\s+(section 7[\s.:-]+(?:deliver(?:ing)?).*?terminal\s+diagnosis(?:'s)?)", s, re.I)
print matches
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that roippi was correct as well, but you put in so much effort to really help me understand. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Negative look-ahead does what it says: specifies a group that cannot match *after* your main expression.  But you don't have anything before it.

Use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!see|under)
```

in lieu of `(?!see )`.

Other comments: you have a case error (terminal should be Terminal) and if you make your entire string "raw" by prepending it with an r like `r'my string'` you don't need to double-escape characters like `\n`.

Comment: thank you for the hints on using the r' flag, very helpful.
However, ((?<!see|under)Section[\s\\n]+7[\s+]+?[-:\\n\.]+?[\s+]+?(Delivering|Deliver)(.*terminal[\s+]+Diagnosis('s)?)?[\.]?)
Still matches: under "Section 7 - Delivering Terminal Diagnosis's"
I want it to not match anything if the word see is present.

Comment: @Baywatch you need a space (or \s) after the negative lookbehind expression.  Or put it into the expression, I suppose.